# Should the car factory be responsible for their CAN dbc?

Tags: can-bus

Which side should be responsible for a correct CAN dbc ?
Developer or car factory ?

Here is the problem I met:

The car factory provided both CAN matrix and CAN dbc,
unfortunately the CAN dbc , when imported into davinci tool, reads many issues,
the developer had to manually modify the dbc to make it work.

My question is : can we insist that the car factory should provide a correct CAN dbc ?
Or should the developer generate CAN dbc himself from the CAN matrix ?

Which side should be responsible for a correct can dbc ?
Developer or car factory ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: This all boils down to if the correct format is required by some standard and if compliance/cerification against that standard is a thing. In this case I believe it's just some proprietary format by Vector, so nobody is "responsible", it's just a tool.

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking, "CAN dbc" to my knowledge is a data descriptor file originally by Vector. This should probably be asked of your legal department, these things are not normally given out to the general public and without a NDA (Non Disclosure Agreement) or something like that. That document should give you a course of action to follow. It also depends on contracts and if you are a first, second, third tier supplier. There is not enough information to begin to answer your question. It also depends on the OEM, country etc. My suggestion take it to a legal forum.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Surely I have signed NDA.

Comment: My question was : if the Car supplier has provided a wrong dbc, what should I do ?  Ask them to provide again ? Or I generate one ( from can matrix ) by myself ?